# How to access knex query results

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

Using knex with express, how can I access the results of a knex query?

Example:

```
var bots = []

response = knex.select('id', 'name').from('robots')
  .then(function(robots){
    console.log(robots);
    bots = robots
  });

console.log(bots)
```

This will log the robots but not not update the `bots` array, which is empty.

EDIT:

As a synchronous workaround, in an express route, I stuck the express block inside the knex block:

```
router.get('/robots', function (req, res) {

  response = knex.select('id', 'name').from('robots').then(function(bots){

    res.render('robots/index', {
      page_title: 'All Robots',
      robots: bots
    }); // res.render

  }); // knex.select

}); // router.get
```

Is this the recommended pattern?

Comment: The `then`'s function callback is asynchronous, basicly it's called when the results from db are available and node continues processing your code if there's any in the mean time. I think you must have noticed you get in terminal first undefined then results. Just search for some tutorials about async nodejs

Comment: I would not set the `knex` action/query to a variable (in your case, `response`). Since `knex` is Promise-based, perform and set variables within the `then()` component (or `catch()` for errors).

So, if you wanted to have a variable `response`, I would set `var response` before the `knex` database query and then, afterwards and inside of the `then()`, I would set `response` to whatever your want from the result of the `knex` query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`knex` uses Promises. Specifically, it uses http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html. `console.log(bots)` will not work because it is called right away, while `.then( ... )` is only called after the `knex` query has been successfully called and run.

Your edited, "synchronous workaround" is the correct method to run the Express response, though you do not need to set that query to `var response` (see my comment on your question for more on that).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using async/await functions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
router.get('/robots', async function (req, res) {
  const bots = await knex.select('id', 'name').from('robots');
  res.render('robots/index', {
    page_title: 'All Robots',
    robots: bots
  }); // res.render 
}); // router.get
```